# Falcon (Waitress) tutorial module object is not callable

Tags: windows, falconframework, waitress

So I am going through Falcon tutorial on windows 10 with venv

```
falcon==1.4.1
waitress==1.1.0
```

User guide went well but it was served with:

```
httpd = simple_server.make_server('127.0.0.1', 8000, app)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The tutorial works with two files for now:

**resource.py**:

```
    import json
    import falcon

    class Resource(object):
        def on_get(self, req, resp):
            doc = {
                'images': [
                    {
                        'href': '/images/1eaf6ef1-7f2d-4ecc-a8d5-6e8adba7cc0e.png'
                    }
                ]
            }
            resp.body = json.dumps(doc, ensure_ascii=False)
            resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
```

**app.py**:

```
import falcon
from .images import Resource
api = application = falcon.API()
images = Resource()
api.add_route('/images', images)
```

**waitress initiated with**:

```
waitress-serve --port=8000 look:app
```

**request made with**:

```
http localhost:8000/images
```

**error response**:

> ERROR:waitress:Exception when serving /images Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "c:\users\ivan\dev\py\projects\falcon\look.venv\lib\site-packages\waitress\channel.py",
>   line 338, in service
>       task.service()   File "c:\users\ivan\dev\py\projects\falcon\look.venv\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py",
>   line 169, in service
>       self.execute()  File "c:\users\ivan\dev\py\projects\falcon\look.venv\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py",
>   line 399, in execute
>       app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Any ideas / inputs how to overcome this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an issue, the tutorial in falcon framework got it wrong with the waitress command.

Here is the related github [issue](https://github.com/falconry/falcon/issues/1256).

The command should be:

```
waitress-serve --port=8000 look.app:api
```